# Display summary of user reviews today, yesterday and other conditions in one query OPTIMIZED

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I have seen many questions related to obtain count on data with different date ranges but in separate queries.
I am required to display how many times each user has accessed today, yesterday and how many times a user has requested the 'File Section'.
So I need to display many columns each one with different count on each user on different date ranges or with specific details.

Here are the scripts for creating and inserting initial data:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `realname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `access_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO users (username,realname) VALUES
("mwazowski","Mike Wazowski"),("jsullivan","James P. Sullivan"),
("rboggs","Randall Boggs"),("hwaternoose","Henry J. Waternoose");

INSERT INTO history (username,access_date,detail) VALUES
("","2020-04-22 12:00:00","publicData"),
("mwazowski","2020-04-22 12:01:00","login"),
("mwazowski","2020-04-22 12:02:00","practice"),
("mwazowski","2020-04-22 12:04:00","files"),
("mwazowski","2020-04-22 12:10:00","logout"),
("","2020-04-23 12:25:00","publicData"),
("","2020-04-23 12:27:00","publicData"),
("jsullivan","2020-04-23 12:30:00","login"),
("jsullivan","2020-04-23 12:35:00","files"),
("jsullivan","2020-04-23 12:40:00","logout"),
("","2020-04-23 12:52:00","publicData"),
("rboggs","2020-04-23 13:00:00","login"),
("rboggs","2020-04-23 13:01:00","files"),
("rboggs","2020-04-23 13:40:00","logout"),
("","2020-04-23 13:43:00","publicData");
```

This is the resultset for table **Users**:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+
| id |  username   |      realname       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | mwazowski   | Mike Wazowski       |
|  2 | jsullivan   | James P. Sullivan   |
|  3 | rboggs      | Randall Boggs       |
|  4 | hwaternoose | Henry J. Waternoose |
|    |             |                     |
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

And this is the resultset for table **History**:

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| id | username  |     access_date     |   detail   |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |           | 2020-04-22 12:00:00 | publicData |
|  2 | mwazowski | 2020-04-22 12:01:00 | login      |
|  3 | mwazowski | 2020-04-22 12:02:00 | practice   |
|  4 | mwazowski | 2020-04-22 12:04:00 | files      |
|  5 | mwazowski | 2020-04-22 12:10:00 | logout     |
|  6 |           | 2020-04-23 12:25:00 | publicData |
|  7 |           | 2020-04-23 12:27:00 | publicData |
|  8 | jsullivan | 2020-04-23 12:30:00 | login      |
|  9 | jsullivan | 2020-04-23 12:35:00 | files      |
| 10 | jsullivan | 2020-04-23 12:40:00 | logout     |
| 11 |           | 2020-04-23 12:52:00 | publicData |
| 12 | rboggs    | 2020-04-23 13:00:00 | login      |
| 13 | rboggs    | 2020-04-23 13:01:00 | files      |
| 14 | rboggs    | 2020-04-23 13:40:00 | logout     |
| 15 |           | 2020-04-23 13:43:00 | publicData |
+----+-----------+---------------------+------------+
```

Here is the query I designed that display counts on access records group by user, date ranges for today and yesterday and specific detail data (records added with field detail='files'):

```
select coalesce(u.realname,"PUBLIC") username,
       coalesce(h2.todayCount,0) nToday,
       coalesce(h3.yesterdayCount,0) nYesterday,
       coalesce(h4.fileCount,0) nFiles
from (select distinct username from history) h1
left join users u on h1.username=u.username
left join (select username,count(1) todayCount from history
    where access_date>=current_date() group by username) h2
    on h1.username=h2.username
left join (select username,count(1) yesterdayCount from history
    where access_date between (current_date()-1) and current_date() group by username) h3
    on h1.username=h3.username
left join (select username,count(1) fileCount from history
    where detail="files" group by username) h4
    on h1.username=h4.username order by h1.username;
```

This query works and display the data as needed, but it gets slower as more data exists and also I might need to add more columns later and that will imply additional reading of all the history. The history table is being read multiple times and if sometime more date ranges are needed it will get worst.
This is the result of the query with the initial data:

```
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
|     username      | nToday | nYesterday | nFiles |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
| PUBLIC            |      4 |          1 |      0 |
| James P. Sullivan |      3 |          0 |      1 |
| Mike Wazowski     |      0 |          4 |      1 |
| Randall Boggs     |      3 |          0 |      1 |
+-------------------+--------+------------+--------+
```

The dates included in the sample data generate the expected result only while today is April 23th.
To make this test data work any future day run the next scripts:

```
UPDATE history SET access_date=concat((curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)," ",time(access_date)) WHERE id<=5;
UPDATE history SET access_date=concat(curdate()," ",time(access_date)) WHERE id>5;
```

Comment: Seeing as id is the PRIMARY KEY in the users table, shouldn't that be the foreign key in the history table (hint: yes it should)

Comment: All my gratitude for pointing out how to improve my table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure I haven't fully understood your requirement. Nevertheless, if it was me, I'd keep the query to something simple like this and handle any remaining display issues in application code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `realname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS history;
CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `history_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT NULL,
  `access_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO users (username,realname) VALUES
("mwazowski","Mike Wazowski"),("jsullivan","James P. Sullivan"),
("rboggs","Randall Boggs"),("hwaternoose","Henry J. Waternoose");

INSERT INTO history (user_id,access_date,detail) VALUES
(NULL,"2020-04-22 12:00:00","publicData"),
(1,"2020-04-22 12:01:00","login"),
(1,"2020-04-22 12:02:00","practice"),
(1,"2020-04-22 12:04:00","files"),
(1,"2020-04-22 12:10:00","logout"),
(NULL,"2020-04-23 12:25:00","publicData"),
(NULL,"2020-04-23 12:27:00","publicData"),
(2,"2020-04-23 12:30:00","login"),
(2,"2020-04-23 12:35:00","files"),
(2,"2020-04-23 12:40:00","logout"),
(NULL,"2020-04-23 12:52:00","publicData"),
(3,"2020-04-23 13:00:00","login"),
(3,"2020-04-23 13:01:00","files"),
(3,"2020-04-23 13:40:00","logout"),
(NULL,"2020-04-23 13:43:00","publicData");

SELECT u.user_id
     , u.username  
     , u.realname          
     , DATE(h.access_date) access_date
     , COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) total
     , COALESCE(SUM(h.detail = 'files'),0) total_files
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN history h
    ON h.user_id = u.user_id
   AND h.access_date >= '2020-04-22 00:00:00' 
   AND h.access_date < '2020-04-24 00:00:00'
 GROUP
    BY u.user_id
     , DATE(h.access_date);

+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-------------+
| user_id | username    | realname            | access_date | total | total_files |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-------------+
|       1 | mwazowski   | Mike Wazowski       | 2020-04-22  |     4 |           1 |
|       2 | jsullivan   | James P. Sullivan   | 2020-04-23  |     3 |           1 |
|       3 | rboggs      | Randall Boggs       | 2020-04-23  |     3 |           1 |
|       4 | hwaternoose | Henry J. Waternoose | NULL        |     1 |           0 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+-------------+-------+-------------+
```

Note, I've amended your schema slightly; with a composite index on (user_id,access_date), this should be fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot Strawberry for your contributions, seems very helpful the use of date in group and the way you use sum function. I see some differences with my example.
The PUBLIC access are not considered, I mean, those records with user_id=null.
In this sample I put 3 sample cases, one of them on previous day and the others in current day, but in the real site, some users enter everyday so the result set will show them repeated.
Finally I was expecting to populate an html table directly with the result set. I will try your solution and rearrange data as needed with code.

Comment: I fixed my history table to use the id instead of the username, also I rearranged my code so to receive a similar query to yours with the needed date range and then used the data to obtain last previous days count. Seems that way is less expensive than trying to populate the html table directly with a query. Also I created a public user so I can count those too.